# Insert MySQL Data into Javascript Array not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Im a beginner in javascript, I try to insert mysql-data which is requested in a while loop
to an javascript array. I tried a lot of codes from the forum here, but nothing works.

The alert i use to check what kind of data is in the array for debugging.

If I set the alert above the push-command, I get a empty array as i should.
But if I move the alert command under the first push command, nothing happens. No alert show up and (i think) no data was added to the array. Can someone tell me why?

Heres my (shortened) code:

```
echo "<script>
                                            var name = []; 
                                            var ip = []; 
                                            var id = []; 
                                        </script>";
                                while ($zeile = $erg->fetch_object()) {
                                    
                                    $
                                    echo "<script>";
                                    echo "name.push('".$zeile->name."');";
                                    echo "alert(name);";
                                    /*echo "ip.push('".$zeile->ip."');";
                                    echo "id.push('".$i."');";*/
                                    echo "</script>";   }
```

Hope someone can help me.

Greetings Tom

Comment: Are there any errors in your developer console? Are you sure there there is data being returned by your query?

Comment: Can you share what's actually being rendered by the PHP code?  Does that give you any hint about why the JavaScript that's being produced isn't working as expected?

Comment: `Can someone tell me why?`...your browser's Console might have some clues? Did you check? It's usually better to use `console.log` for debugging too, rather than `alert`. But I've literally no idea why you'd do this like this. We don't know what's in $json_array exactly, but presumably JS didn't like something about it. However, if you want to make a JS array from PHP data, just use `json_encode()` in PHP - JSON can be interpreted as a JS literal. No need for silly fiddly loops. And using `echo` for this...urgh, way to make your life more difficult. A better demo: https://3v4l.org/AF9X5

Comment: Or a slightly more complex example: https://3v4l.org/Qa8LW

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, I the $json_array is from a test. Normally I would set $zeile->name to add the Name from MySQL Table to the name-array.

Comment: Ok. But this is a really strange (and error-prone) way to do it. Here's a worked example of a sane approach: https://phpize.online/sql/mysql57/70bf51ebb9b305af2689b235e8e3d5d3/php/php81/4ab408da7ef088ccfc9e1ef64db4a475/ . And then you don't even need messy separate arrays for the name, ip and ids in JavaScript....instead you can just take the properties you need from the objects in the main list, whenever you need them

Comment: Or if you prefer to use mysqli rather than PDO, then: https://phpize.online/sql/mysql57/70bf51ebb9b305af2689b235e8e3d5d3/php/php81/a3d4b14375ed91197912c0ccf34a9d3a/

Comment: why are you using echo for first `script` tag? isn't is pure js code? is there any error in browser console?

Comment: It looks that `$` character right after while loop opening bracket is causing a php error.

Answer (score -1):

I didn't understand clearly in your question but I try to fix your code and make it's working.

```
<?php
echo "<script>
    let name = []; 
    let ip_address = []; 
    let index = [];
";
$zeile = [
   [
    "name" => "Name 1",
    "ip" => "IP 1"
   ],
   [
    "name" => "Name 2",
    "ip" => "IP 2"
   ],
];
foreach ($zeile as $key => $value) {
    echo "
        name.push('".$value['name']."');
        ip_address.push('".$value['ip']."');
        index.push('".$key."');
    ";
}
echo "
    console.log(name);
    console.log(ip_address);
    console.log(index);
";
echo "</script>";
```

It will render like this.

```js
let name = []; 
let ip = []; 
let id = [];

name.push('Name 1');
ip.push('IP 1');
id.push('0');

name.push('Name 2');
ip.push('IP 2');
id.push('1');

console.log(name);
console.log(ip);
console.log(id);
```

Explanation:
I only change echo pattern to easyer to read the code, remove $ because It will did the code error and change while loop to foreach

FYI: I don't have example of $zeile = $erg->fetch_object() so I will mockup this value by myself

Comment: please explain your code why its working

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).